# gmail compose box not opened with subject and content using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, angular

The js window.open does not open the  IOS compose box, but in android, browser works fine subject and the content is appended.

code:

```
 window.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&mailto=sri@gmail.com&su=" + 'subject' + "&body=" + 'body' + "&ui=2&tf=1&pli=1", 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=648,height=395');
```

how to open the Gmail compose box with the subject and content of the mail for all browser compatibility

Comment: What if the user doesn't have a Gmail account? I'd suggest you use a `mailto:` link instead, as this will open the default mail application on the client device.

Comment: using mailto the above code @RoryMcCrossan, in IOS compose box not opened, my expectation is opened  compose box and append subject and body content